# Crear una función para validar el registro de un documento

Tags: python, web2py

Tengo esta tabla

```
db.define_table('registro',
                Field('numero_documento', 'string'),
                Field('remitente', 'string'),
                Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios'),
                Field('fecha_ingreso', 'datetime', default=now),
                format='%(numero_documento)s'
                )
```

Se que poniendo `unique=True` en el campo `numero_documento` puedo hacer que no se repita, pero estoy creando esta función

```
def validar_documento(values, id, table):
    try:
        documento = values['numero_documento']
        data_documento = db.registro(db.registro.numero_documento)
        for doccumento_values in data_documento:
            if doccumento_values:
                if db.registro((db.registro.numero_documento==documento)):
                    form.errors['documento'] = 'Ya existe un documento con Numero %s' % documento
            elif len(documento) < 4:
                form.errors['documento'] = 'El numero de documento es inválido'
        numero_documento = data_documento['numero_documento']
        db[table][id] = dict(numero_documento=numero_documento)
    except:
        pass
    return
```

para validarlo y a su vez que el numero del documento no tenga menos de 4 digitos, y la utilizo así:

```
db.registro._after_insert.append(lambda values, id: validar_documento(values, id, 'numero_documento'))
```

pero no me da resultado y tampoco me da error ...

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo, en la función `validar_documento` no estas devolviendo nada, si la quieres  usar como lambda tienes que retornar los registros a agregar a la base de datos.

Lo otro que veo también es que el `elif` debiese ser un `if` y tiene que estar fuera del `for`, de lo contrario.

Por último, la variable `form`, es una variable global?